# How do I combine spring errors tag logic with jstl logic

Tags: html, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have the following div for displaying my spring messages.  errorContainer DIV and errText UL contain the classes to show my error icon and format my error message text.

```
<c:if test="${not empty modelAttr}">
  <spring:hasBindErrors name="${modelAttr}">
    <div class="errorContainer">
      <ul class="errText">
        <form:errors path="*" element="li" delimiter=</li><li>" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  </spring:hasBindErrors>
</c:if>
```

I want to also use the errorContainer(or a duplicate div) for my jquery error messages.  I need to figure out how to rewrite the previous jstl and spring tag logic to put another div on the page only when the c:if and spring:hasBindErrors tags above evaluate to false together.  I need to base my conditional on the outcome of both of these tags without putting my new div within them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add another condition in the jstl tag to check when your conditions are met?

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty modelAttr}">   <%-- evaulates to true --%>
      <spring:hasBindErrors name="${modelAttr}">
        <div class="errorContainer">
          <ul class="errText">
             <form:errors path="*" element="li" delimiter=</li><li>" />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </spring:hasBindErrors>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise> <%-- evaulates to false --%>
        Your spring test in here
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: This solution will only evaluate the first condition, and will work logically only when the modelAttr object is not empty and modelAttr hasBindErrors = true.  It will not evaluate properly when modelAttr is not empty but modelAttr hasBindErrors = false, because it will then skip the 'otherwise'.  I ultimately used a c:set with a boolean variable within the two conditions and then used that boolean as the conditional on the second section of logic.